# How to format/convert Phone Number fields to I164 format in Salesforce

Tags: appexchange, data, formatting

I am looking for any recommendation on #phone number #cleanup on contacts. Is there any app which cleanup Salesforce contact phone number and put them in international format (I164), so that CTI can read is without errors.

I am not looking for any hacks using regex or apex code, it should work globally.

Twillo requires this format and our data is not clean - http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/how-do-i-format-phone-numbers-to-work-internationally

Comment: Was any solution ever found to this question?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to know how as well in salesforce so the call journalling works. As far as making it work with Twilio, you need to make sure your outbound call format rulle formats it as e164, so as the call leaves the PBX for Twilio's SIP trunk. In 3CX this is in the SIP Trunk Outbound Rules. So you configure the number destined for Twilio's trunk as Strip the Zero, replace with + your default country code.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You could ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it you can link to this question for reference (just click "Share" at the bottom left of the post to get a URL) if relevant/helpful.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/184668)